# How to avoid special characters in Spring MVC

Tags: spring

Hi am doing sever side validation for form fields see am getting all the error messages properly but How to avoid special characters like % # $ ^ & * for each input fields and how to make input box border gets red when i get error messages

**To avoid special characters i have to use ESAPI.validator().getValidInput
How to use below try catch code In validator class to avoid special characters**

```
    try
    {
ESAPI.validator().getValidInput("Validationofmobilenumber", mobilenumber, "Onlynumber", 200, false);
            ESAPI.validator().getValidInput("Validationofinput", Studentname, "Onlycharacters", 200, false);
    }
    catch (ValidationException e) {
                ESAPI.log().error(Logger.EVENT_FAILURE, e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("in validation");
                addActionError("Do not enter special character like % # $ ^ & *...... ");

            } catch (IntrusionException ie) {
                ESAPI.log().error(Logger.EVENT_FAILURE, ie.getMessage());
    addActionError("Do not enter special character like % # $ ^ & *...... ");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);

            }
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class RegistrationController {

    @Autowired
    CustomerValidator customerValidator;



     @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String viewRegistrationPage(Model model) {
          Customer customer = new Customer();
            model.addAttribute("customer", customer);
            return "register";
        }

     @RequestMapping(value = "/doRegister", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String doLogin(@Valid Customer customer, BindingResult result,Model model) {
         model.addAttribute("customer",customer);
         customerValidator.validate(customer, result);
          if(result.hasErrors()){
              return "register";
          }

          return "home";
        }

    public CustomerValidator getCustomerValidator() {
        return customerValidator;
    }

    public void setCustomerValidator(CustomerValidator customerValidator) {
        this.customerValidator = customerValidator;
    }

}
```

**Model**
public class Customer {

```
@NotEmpty   
    @Email
    private String emailId;

    @Size(min=8,max=15)
    private String password;


    @Size(min=8,max=15)
    private String confPassword;

    private int age;

    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }

    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getConfPassword() {
        return confPassword;
    }

    public void setConfPassword(String confPassword) {
        this.confPassword = confPassword;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

**Validator**

```
@Component
public class CustomerValidator implements Validator {

    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return Customer.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        Customer customer = (Customer)target;
        int age = customer.getAge();
        String password = customer.getPassword();
        String confPassword = customer.getConfPassword();


        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "age", "customer.age.empty");



        //Business validation
        if(!password.equals(confPassword)){
            errors.rejectValue("password","customer.password.missMatch");
        }


        if(age < 18 || age > 60){
            errors.rejectValue("age", "customer.age.range.invalid");
        }       
    }
}
```

**Jsp**

```
        <tr>
            <td>Enter your E-mail:</td>
            <td><form:input path="emailId" /></td>
            <td><form:errors path="emailId" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Enter your Age:</td>
            <td><form:input path="age"/></td>
            <td><form:errors path="age" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Enter your password:</td>
            <td><form:password path="password"  showPassword="true"/></td>
            <td><form:errors path="password" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;"/></td>
        </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>Confirm your password:</td>
            <td><form:password path="confPassword"  showPassword="true"/></td>
            <td><form:errors path="confPassword" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Click here to Register"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

**Properties**

```
NotEmpty.customer.emailId=Email Id is required. 
Email.customer.emailId=valid email id is required.
Size.customer.password=Password should be minimum of 8 and maximum of 15 characters.
Size.customer.confPassword=Password should be minimum of 8 and maximum of 15 characters.
customer.age.empty = Age is required
customer.age.range.invalid = Age should be between 18 to 60
customer.password.missMatch = password and confirm password do not match
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For validation use @Pattern annotation like this:

```
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\\-\\/+=@_ ]*$")
    @NotEmpty   
    @Email
    private String emailId;
```

And for error field red border, add a css class for errors and put css style for that class and put that in head block of jsp or in the css file that you have.

```
    <tr>
        <td>Enter your E-mail:</td>
        <td><form:input path="emailId" /></td>
        <td><form:errors path="emailId" cssClass="error" /></td>
    </tr>

    <style>
        .error {
            color: red;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
    </style>
```

If you want to use ESAPI validator, add this rule in your ESAPI.properties

```
Validator.ValidInput=^[a-zA-Z0-9.\\-\\/+=@_ ]*$
```

And then add following for each of your input in Validator class, i'm giving only one for example.

```
        try {
            if (!ESAPI.validator().isValidInput("ValidationOfPassword", password, "ValidInput", 200, false)) {
                errors.rejectValue("password","customer.password.missMatch");//replace your msg property in second param
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //something gone wrong
            e.printStackTrace();
            errors.rejectValue("password","customer.password.missMatch");//replace your msg property in second param
        }
```

Comment: if you are using maven, add your properties files in resources directory.

Comment: i have not using maven in struts project i just add under project

Answer (score 0):

On your field, you can use `javax.validation.constraints.Pattern` annotation and then use something like "[\w]*" that means only alphanumeric characters.

Comment: I think you would need to add some anchors to that like ^[\w]*$ so that it tries to match the pattern against the whole field and not just part of it